# How to create a recurrent connection between two Dense layers in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, recurrence

Before starting, there is a [very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63899389/how-to-create-a-recurrent-connection-between-2-layers-in-tensorflow-keras), but it was asked 2 years ago and I would like to do this *without* creating a custom class. Essentially, I have the simple feedforward neural network:

[image]

Which can be created with:

```
import keras

inputs = keras.layers.Input(1,)
hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(10, name='hidden1')(inputs)
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(10, name='hidden2')(hidden1)
outputs = keras.layers.Dense(1, name='outputs')(hidden2)

model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

But I would like:

[image]

I know that I can concatenate the `inputs` and `hidden2` layer outputs like:

```
concat_layer = keras.layers.Concatenate()([inputs, outputs])
```

but how can I replace the inputs of the `hidden1` layer?

Comment: This is impossible because `hidden2` needs `hidden1`, which needs `hidden2`, which needs `hidden1` etc. You need to define the recurrence more clearly, e.g. is it supposed to have across-batch memory (like in the question you linked), or within-batch memory over time steps like an RNN, or something else. In any case, I highly doubt you can do this without writing custom code (possibly based on an `RNN` with `stateful=True`, for example).

Comment: @xdurch0 across-batch memory indeed. I also think it is impossible, but wanted to see if anyone thought otherwise. For context; I don't want a custom class because I would like to save my model easily. [This is possible with TF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51806852/cant-save-custom-subclassed-model), but not with earlier versions :(