Recurrent Keras model with functional API
I am trying to create a simple recurrent model using Keras. My objective is to have multiple layers, and to connect only the final output of the last layer as an input into the first layer at the next timestep. My understanding is that this cannot be achieved by using SimpleRNN layers, because chaining those adds an internal recursion inside each layer, not a single one from the very end to the very beginning.
Here is a non-functional example of what I would like to achieve:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

base_input = Input(shape=[2, 5], name='base_input')
dense_1 = Dense(20, input_shape=[2, 5], name='dense_1')(base_input)
dense_2 = Dense(20, name='dense_2')(dense_1)
base_output = Dense(units=5, name='base_output')(dense_2)

base_model = Model(inputs=[base_input], outputs=base_output)

outer_input = Input(shape=[1, 5], name='outer_input')
outer_model = Model(inputs=[outer_input, base_output], outputs=base_output)

As you see, the base model takes 2*5 inputs, and provides 5 outputs. I want these to be the concatenation of 5 "real" inputs, and the 5 previous outputs. Clearly there is a problem, because simply specifying the same tensor base_output in both the inputs and outputs is not quite what Keras wants. I don't see a way to connect the layers themselves, i.e. outer_input and base_output to base_input.
Is there a clean solution to this? I would prefer to use only simple Dense layers as components, but that may not be possible.

Apparently this question is very similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75201174/how-to-create-a-recurrent-connection-between-two-dense-layers-in-keras. I will dig into that, and post here what I found.

Went through the comments on the other post. They say this will only work with a custom layer. I'm open to suggestions in that direction.

Why don't you write a while loop (until you have credible outer_input data) where you assign inputs=[outer_input, base_output] and go over the loop, the initial base_output could be all zeros and updated through the loop.
